# Javascript: AppendChild

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I was learning about `appendChild` and have so far come up with this code:

```js
var blah = "Blah!";
var t = document.createElement("table"),
  tb = document.createElement("tbody"),
  tr = document.createElement("tr"),
  td = document.createElement("td");

t.style.width = "100%";
t.style.borderCollapse = 'collapse';

td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(blah));

// note the reverse order of adding child        
tr.appendChild(td);
tb.appendChild(tr);
t.appendChild(tb);

document.getElementById("theBlah").appendChild(t);
```

```html
<div id="theBlah">d</div>
```

But that gives me an error saying `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can also place your script below *theBlah* and it will work without an *onload* listener.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try wrapping your JavaScript in an onload function.  So first add:

```
<body onload="load()">
```

Then put your javascript in the load function, so:

```
function load() {
    var blah="Blah!";
    var t  = document.createElement("table"),
    tb = document.createElement("tbody"),
    tr = document.createElement("tr"),
    td = document.createElement("td");

    t.style.width = "100%";
    t.style.borderCollapse = 'collapse';

    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(blah)); 

    // note the reverse order of adding child        
    tr.appendChild(td);
    tb.appendChild(tr);
    t.appendChild(tb);

   document.getElementById("theBlah").appendChild(t);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

The script is being run before the page completes loading. Which is why document.getElementById("theBlah") returns null.

Either use something like jQuery or simply something like

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    var blah="Blah!";
    var t  = document.createElement("table"),
    tb = document.createElement("tbody"),
    ...
    //the rest of your code here
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that `document.getElementById("theBlah")` returns null.  The reason why is that your code is running before the `theBlah` element has been created.  You should place your code in an `onload` event handler.

Answer (score 2):

proper way (rows & cols & the random innerText is set dynamically ...by you)
this way is probably not the shortest but by way the fastest to build a table.
It’s also a full table with `thead` and filled with random text:

1. use native JavaScript (not slowing down JQuery)
2. `(function(){})()` executes the code before body is loading
3. doesn’t have problems with other variables outside the function
4. and pass the document so you have shorter variables
5. there is a way to shorten the function by using clone node... but it’s slower and maybe not supported by all browsers
6. use `createDocumentFragment()` to create the `tr`’s. If you have a lot of rows this helps to build the DOM faster.

```
    (function (d) {
        var rows = 10,
            cols = 3,
            t = d.createElement('table'),
            the = d.createElement('thead'),
            tb = d.createElement('tbody'),
            tr = d.createElement('tr');
        t.style.width = "100%";
        t.style.borderCollapse = 'collapse';
        for (var a = 0; a < cols; a++) {
            var th = d.createElement('th');
            th.innerText = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
            tr.appendChild(th);
        };
        the.appendChild(tr);
        var f = d.createDocumentFragment();
        for (var a = 0; a < rows; a++) {
            var tr = d.createElement('tr');
            for (var b = 0; b < cols; b++) {
                var td = d.createElement('td');
                td.innerText = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                tr.appendChild(td);
            }
            f.appendChild(tr);
        }
        tb.appendChild(f);
        t.appendChild(the);
        t.appendChild(tb);
        window.onload = function () {
            d.body.appendChild(t)
        };
    })(document)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can just link your JavaScript to your html using the defer attribute.

```
<script src="script.js" defer></script>
```

This way your JavaScript will not run until after the page has loaded.

Answer (score -2):

Do yourself and us a favor and use JQuery. Everything becomes much simpler.

```
$('div.SomeDiv').append($('<table></table>').css('width','100%').append($('<tbody></tbody>').append($('<tr></tr>').append($('<td></td>').html("Blah Text"))))); // Everything else you want to add here...
```

Comment: I am only using JS to make some changes to a Firefox plugin... i am not sure what their policies are on JQuery...

Comment: JQuery is translated finally into Javascript you know...
I'm hard to believe there is a different...

Comment: @Ryan - if you want to learn javascript, don't start with jQuery. If you learn javascript first, you will be able to use libraries and frameworks much more effectively and efficiently later.

Comment: @Yossi jQuery doesn't get translated, it's native JavaScript (during development it's built with Ant, but that doesn't matter). You can open jQuery source file and change anything you want, in JavaScript.

Comment: jQuery is a fantastic library, but this answer has little place here. The example you have given is sloppy and using jQuery in every instance as you've suggested is often over kill. @Ryan's advice is very wise

Comment: This is the completely wrong advice. I learned the hard way to **not** learn jQuery first. It doesn't teach you the crucial foundations you need to know.