# javascript iframe permission

Tags: javascript, ajax, iframe, firebug

I have a webpage (parent) on localhost, 
with an iframe showing another url (child; which is part of a different webapp) on localhost.

Using javascript in parent-page, I am trying to "peek" into the iframe.contentDocument.
(The iframe is showing a list of items, and if the list is empty, I simply want to hide the iframe completely.)

Now, the problem is, when trying to retrieve the element iframe.contentDocument.body,
I get error-msg in firefox: 
   **Permission denied to access property 'body'**

In IE, I simply get:
   **Error: 'body' is null or not an object.**

Anyone, knows how to get around this?

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery cross domain iframe scripting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083112/jquery-cross-domain-iframe-scripting)

Comment: no, this is different. this is not a cross-domain issue. both url:s are on localhost, same port (default 80) and same protocol (https).

Comment: You should use port 443 for https... But anyhow, I would try placing a breakpoint in firebug (right before the error), and see if the 'body' member exists, and if it does, what's its value. If this doesn't work, please add some more code to show exactly where this is called and under what circumstances.

Comment: 443... yes, u are right of course ... i should have written "default", period  :) ---- but body does apparently exists, otherwise it doesnt give that msg "Permission denied" --- i dont understand it, but to me it seems the firefox concludes its a same-origin-policy violation, while Im certain it is not....

Answer (score 0):

I've seen two potential work-arounds for this error where body returns null. One is to simply bury your script at the bottom of the body, so that it doesn't execute before body has been built out. But everybody hates inline scripts, no?

Another, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867003/javascript-appendchild), is to use an onload function for your body, which also ensures that body exists before the function is called.

Both seem to work equivalently well.