# How can I use innerHTML without removing entire html inside of tag?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I have searched almost whole internet but couldn't able to get a solution about this..

Suppose that we have a div element with some html inside of it. After selecting this tag by its id (or other selectors, whatever) and if I use "innerHTML" method, I lost all html inside of the tag. What can i do to not destroy html parts inside of the tag? I just want to add something "more", not to "destroy all" and then insert something into new instead.

```
document.getElementById('something').innerHTML = document.getElementById('something').innerHTML + new_html_to_append;
```

the method above doesn't work for 3rd iteration, or in a for loop so it's useless for me.. i need something fits infinite supplementation.

Thank You!

(I know .append() method but i am not allowed to use JQuery there.)

Comment: Show your loop code that doesn't work. The snippet you posted shouldn't have problems, probably it's your loop logic what's wrong...

Comment: `document.getElementById('something').innerHTML += new_html_to_append;`? or indeed `appendChild` which is pure javascript after all - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild

Comment: You can use plain JS `appendChild`

Comment: so use the dom method appendChild! :)

Comment: pls share your code so that we can see the loop you have used

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867003/javascript-appendchild

Answer (score -1, accepted):

appendChild()

...................................

Answer (score 0):

Using `innerHTML()` can result in some unexpected behaviour. Look at alternatives like `appendChild()` from here:

[How to append data to div using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677799/how-to-append-data-to-div-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Use AppendChild() .In using this function be aware to use the correct functions like if you have to add HTML Element like div.Then Use

```
obj=document.createElement(something);
document.getElementById("something").appendChild(obj);
```

But if its a Text Node then

```
obj=document.createTextNode(something);
document.getElementById("something").appendChild(obj);
```

Comment: all developers on the project have added something new into code since years that i can't count and now it's a total mess. I can't copy whole code here cos there are a lot of node it contains including an old ajax engine, some parts works only in server, etc. long story short, a total mess.

by the way, appendChild works for now, thank you!

Comment: so you mean you don't know whether the something is Element or just text ,right?